# Extracting menu item text in Perl GTK+2

Tags: perl, menu, gtk

I have a pop up menu over a tree view where the user selects the machine to restore from backup.  I want to simplify the interface and make a submenu that will be dynamically generated according to files available. This is what I have so far:

```
$restore_item->set_submenu($arc_menu);
open( FILE, "archives.db" ) or die("Unable to open file");
foreach (<FILE>) {
    # if record is correct
    if ( $_ =~ /archive=(.+)/ ) {
        my $item = new Gtk2::MenuItem( "_" . $1 );
        $item->signal_connect( 'activate' => sub { print "selected\n"; });
        $arc_menu->append($item);
    }
}
close(FILE);
```

But, in real life I will have to read the menu item text as files can dynamically change and I can't rely on count or something. I can't understand how to get the menu item text from callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There at least two alternatives.  Passing the optional parameter to the callback (user_data) or getting the label from the Gtk2::MenuItem (`$item->get_label`).

For the former, you could use something like:

```
$item->signal_connect('activate' => \&on_button_activate, $1);
[...]

sub on_button_activate
{
        # Do whatever you need.  The second parameters is
        # user_data (the filename in this case).
        my ($item, $user_data) = @_;
        print $item->get_label;
        print $user_data;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get ***   Can't locate object method "get_label" via package "Gtk2::CheckMenuItem" at ./foo.pl line 80.  Is this not supported in libgtk2-perl 2:1.223-1build3?

Comment: Found my answer: print $item->child->get_label;